# replace NA in df[2:3,1:2] with blanks

Tags: r

This seems like it should be straightforward.  I need to replace rows 2 and 3 by columns 1 and 2 in a dataframe with blanks.  They are currently NA and causing a problem with the package I am trying to use.

Any advice?

```
a <- c(1, NA, NA, 2, 3)
b <- c(5, NA, NA, 2, 6)
c <- c(4, 6, 7.6, 2, 1)
abc <- cbind(a,b,c)
abc

     a  b   c
[1,]  1  5 4.0
[2,] NA NA 6.0
[3,] NA NA 7.6
[4,]  2  2 2.0
[5,]  3  6 1.0
```

edit1:  There are other NAs in the data set and the data set is rather large.  Replacing all NA is not appropriate in this case.  I also cant change the column to strings.

edit2:  Problem Solved!  I was creating any empty df of NA and rbinding it to create the first two columns.  I used iShouldUseAName to replace the NA before doing the rbind. Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem it is causing?

Comment: Is it a public package? If so, can you share the package and the function that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually easiest. Indexing by matrix:

```
abc[is.na(abc)] <- ""
```

It should be noted that this will result in you converting your columns to character vectors.

Maybe let us know what the package error is and we can suggest a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about the printing aspect, you could do

```
> print(abc, na.print = "")
     a b   c
[1,] 1 5 4.0
[2,]     6.0
[3,]     7.6
[4,] 2 2 2.0
[5,] 3 6 1.0
```

Comment: If you wish to replace them with the empty string "", you unfortunately can't do this without changing the type of the column to character.